# What is the term for a safety feature that prevents operation in unsafe conditions?

Tags: terminology, technical

I'm thinking about things like the switches in a rice cooker that won't let you turn them on without actually adding rice and water to the pot, or a handle bar on a lawn mower that turns the engine off if you let go.  Is there a specific term for those kinds of safety features?

They are the safety features that prevent bad things from happening, in contrast to a safety feature like a plastic guard that saves you if something goes wrong.

Comment: Very often they are simply called a "safety".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One word to describe this is **fail safe** (adjective and noun):

> incorporating some feature for automatically counteracting the effect of an anticipated possible source of failure.
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fail-safe)</sub>

The one example you mentioned is on the [Wikipedia page for fail safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-safe):

> Lawnmowers and snow blowers have a hand-closed lever that must be held down at all times. If it is released, it stops the blade's or rotor's rotation. This is also a dead man's switch.

Comment: A lever that switches off a machine when the operator lets go of it is sometimes called a **dead man's handle**.

Comment: @Laurel: Yes, that's what I'm looking for, thanks.  I'll accept the answer when I'm allowed to

Answer (score 0):

> What is the term for a safety feature that prevents operation in
>   unsafe conditions?

A **foolproof** device/maching could imply 'incorporating' such safety features'

**foolproof**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/foolproof)

> 1. Designed so as to be impervious to human incompetence, error, or misuse: a foolproof detonator; a foolproof safety lock.